# Cantor Set self homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $a, b \in C$ where $C$ denotes the cantor set. I want to show that there exists a homeomorphism from $C$ onto itself such that $f(a) = b$. I don't know how to start with this. Is there any hint or suggestion?

Comment: Do you know that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology?

Comment: I have only been introduced to the concept of Cantor set in the context of metric spaces. Is there any simpler approach to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: So when you speak of the Cantor set, you mean specifically the middle-thirds Cantor set as a subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes. The cantor set I'm talking about is the one that is a subset of [0,1], being constructed by removing the middle thirds.

Comment: Do you know that it consists of those $x\in[0,1]$ that have ternary representations using only the digits $0$ and $2$?

Comment: Yes, I've been introduced to that.

Comment: Okay; I think that I may be able to point you in a useful direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ have the ternary representations $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ and $0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots$, respectively, where $a_n,b_n\in\{0,2\}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so that

$$a=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{a_n}{3^n}\quad\text{and}\quad b=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{b_n}{3^n}\,.$$

Let $D=\{n\in\Bbb N:a_n\ne b_n\}$. For $c\in\{0,2\}$ let $\bar c=2-c$, and define

$$h:C\to C:\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{c_n}{3^n}\to\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{c_n'}{3^n}\,,$$

where

$$c_n'=\begin{cases}
\bar c_n,&\text{if }n\in D\\
c_n,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $h(a)=b$ (and $h(b)=a$), and it’s very easy to see that $h$ is a bijection that is its own inverse. Thus, all that remains is to show that $h$ is continuous, and for now, at least, I’ll leave it to you to try to do that. (Intuitively speaking, this map simply interchanges two of the closed intervals at each level $n$ of the construction of $C$ for which $n\in D$.)

Comment: Thank you! I will attempt to finish the problem.

Comment: @ddth: You’re welcome!