# How to prove existence of homeomorphism from the Cantor set onto itself

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

> Prove that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct points in the Cantor set $C$, then there is a homeomorphism $h$ of $C$ onto $C$ such that $h(x)=y$.

This question was asked in my analysis quiz and I was unable to prove it.
I am unable to think about such a map. Can you please help me with that?

I will work rest of details by myself.

Comment: One-liner: $C=(\mathbb{Z}/2)^\infty$, so translation by $y-x$ would do.

Comment: Since this is an analysis course, I’m going to guess that you mean specifically the middle-thirds Cantor set; [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885579/cantor-set-self-homeomorphism/3885607#3885607) should at least get you started. You can leave a question for me there if you can’t finish it off.